# display error message on the top of my form with with jquery

Tags: jquery

i need to know how i can display errors messages on the top of my form with  jquery
im using jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js and jquery-form-validator/2.1.38/jquery.form-validator.min.js
so if it is possible to help me that's gonna be great
here is a sample of my form validate with jquery form validator

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.1.38/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>

 <body>


    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="">
      <table width="325" border="1">



        <tr>
          <td>Pseudo</td>
          <td>
          <input name="user" data-validation="length alphanumeric" 
             data-validation-length="3-12" data-validation-error-msg="The user name has to be an alphanumeric value between 3-12 characters" />
     </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password</td>
          <td>
          <input type="password" name="password" data-validation="strength" 
             data-validation-strength="2" required>
       </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password confirmation</td>
          <td>
            <input type="password" name="Password_confirmation" data-validation="confirmation" required/>
          </td>
      </table>
    </form>


    <script>

      $.validate({
        modules : 'location, date, security, file',
        onModulesLoaded : function() {
          $('#country').suggestCountry();
        }
      });

      // Restrict presentation length
      $('#presentation').restrictLength( $('#pres-max-length') );

    </script>
    <script>
    $("#form1").validate({
      errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",
      wrapper: "li",
      submitHandler: function() { alert("Submitted!") }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: You're selecting an item id `messageBox` in your validate code, but there is no html element with ID `messageBox` in the code that you posted.

Comment: You could consider using a separate library like toastr (https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) to show the error/message.

Comment: what i should do ? create a div and put the errors messages on it?